# Should I pay tax for previous months because of employer's fault?

Tags: united-kingdom, tax-deduction

I have started in a new job on 30th of November,  2019. I could not get my contract until the last day of December,  which, in addition was not agreed salary as per interview process. Salary is 20k on the contract.

On top of this,  I have been told by the owner, that because she has the bookkeeper on holidays, I will be paid £1666 to my bank account (which was paid), but my taxes for December will be excempt from my January payslip, plus the taxes from January.  (Around: 1666-300-300=1000)

Can the taxes be deducted backwords? Is it the legitimate process? Can 2 months taxes been taken away from one salary, which is already nearly minimum? Am I in any position to argue this and whom can I complain if I have to?

Another issue, as it is not the agreed salary,  if I leave the position now, and I worked for less than a month, will I still be paying taxes? For this month and for previous.

Thank you for your help !

Comment: Can you tell us your location?

Comment: @dwizum because of £, can it be anywhere but the UK?

Comment: They're paying you less than the contract, and not deducting taxes.  Seems **very** sketchy.  I'd look for a new job.

Comment: When did you actually get paid? Taxes depend on when you get paid, not when you do the work.

Comment: I'm a bit confused. Whenever you get paid, you will own taxes on it, whether the employer deducts them or not - deducting them from your paycheck is generally preferable so that you're paying estimated taxes throughout the year and don't get one big bill at the end of the year. If the employer didn't deduct taxes in December, you'll still have to pay them at some point - deducting them from January just catches you up so your estimated tax payment is current. If you don't deduct it from January, you'll just have to pay it yourself later on. None of this changes your final tax bill.

Comment: Do you have a December payslip? What does it say about taxable pay and tax deducted?

Answer (score 5):

If you have income, you will pay income tax.

Your employer has front-loaded your first two months pay, paying more in December, and less in January. This is to your benefit, as you have the use of the money earlier than you would have had the accountant not been on holiday.

Your problem with the salary in the contract not matching the offer letter (you did get an offer in writing, right?) is probably better asked on [Workplace.SE](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/).